# Was Applozic repository removed from GitHub?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, chat, applozic

Our mobile app project uses Applozic SDK for in-app chat. Today we tried to build the project in a new PC. However, the build was failed both in Android and iOS.

```
// Android
Failed to resolve: com.applozic.communication.message:mobicomkit:5.76

// iOS
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Chat-iOS-Framework.git/' not found
```

Anyway, the project that had been built before can be still built and is working. Of course, we'll use alternative later, but for now we still want to use it temporarily. Is there any way we can re-use that SDK from other PC?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes they are shutting down. However, is there any way we can re-use that SDK from other PC temporarily during the time we are finding the alternative?

Comment: At best, that may not be easy. The dependency presumably lives (for a while) in the Gradle cache of the working PC. You would need to find it there. However, it has been quite some time since I have ever tried that, and I do not know the details. Nor do I know how easy it will be for you to identify the transitive dependencies needed by that SDK.